# Buffer types only allowed as function local variables, but that's what I'm doing

Tags: python, cython

Cython doesn't like numpy arrays in closures?

```
%%cython
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np

def f(np.ndarray[double, ndim=1] a):
    def g (double b):
        return a+b

    return g(1)
```

Using the stable version 0.24, I get:

```
Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np

def f(np.ndarray[double, ndim=1] a):
     ^
------------------------------------------------------------

cython_magic.pyx:4:6: Buffer types only allowed as function local variables
```

If I get rid of the definition of `g`, it compiles/works fine.

Comment: If the goal of using `cython` is to produce fast C code, why use fancy dynamic Python constructs?  Wouldn't it be better use Python where the flexibility matters, and Cython where speed matters?

Comment: @hpaulj, I'm in the process of cythonizing some code that runs too slowly. I have functions in several variables where I need to do something fast in one of the variables (say, numerical integration, gradient descent, etc.) so I need closures. I thought I could get away with a python call overhead

Comment: Have you tried the newer memoryview syntax? I'm not sure if it works but it might be worth a look...

Comment: This error has been addressed in the past.  3 SO came up in a google search: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23838241/cython-says-buffer-types-only-allowed-as-function-local-variables-even-for-ndarr, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8808216/cython-buffer-declarations-for-object-members, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13024357/converting-python-numpy-code-to-cython-issue-with-arrays-buffer-types-only

Comment: @hpaulj, I read those before I posted my question and did not find them useful. Could you please be more specific about how they would help solve my problem?

Comment: @DavidW: the memoryview approach is a little too general and doesn't permit things like multiplying an array by a scalar (without a loop), so I'm sticking to numpy types

Answer (score 2):

There's a few work-rounds:

1. Only assign the type to the variable within the inner function:

   ```
   def f(a):
       def g (double b):
           cdef np.ndarray[double, ndim=1] a_typed = a
           return a_typed+b

       return g(1)
   ```

   This has a small cost associated with checking the type on each call of `g`, the significance of which depends on how much other work you're doing in `g`.
2. Use a mixture of memoryviews and untyped variables.

   ```
   def f(a):
      cdef double[:] memview_of_a = a

      def g(double b):
          memview_of_a[0] = 0 # example of indexing operation
          return a+b

      return g(1)
   ```

   The thing to remember here is that `memview_of_a` and `a` look at the same data, so you can access it in two different ways. Array indexing is quick with the memoryview. Things like scalar operations on arrays aren't actually affected by the type information so there's really no reason to force it to be a specific type.

In summary, it's a limitation, but there are workrounds (although they aren't very neat).