# How to avoid using function inside pyx file (Cython)?

Tags: python, cython, cythonize

In am using Cython. I want to know if it is necessary to use a function (`def somefunction()`) in my `.pyx` file.

This is the present way in which I am defining my `.pyx` file (say `pyxfname.pyx`):

```
from __future__ import division
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np

def somefunction():
    cdef int i, j
    cdef np.ndarray[double, mode="c", ndim=2] Kappa = np.zeros( [10 , 10], dtype=np.float64)

    for i in range(0,10):
        for j in range(0,10):
            Kappa[i,j] += 1     

    print "Hello world"
```

This is how the python file (say `pyfile.py`) which calls the `pyx` file is structured:

```
#Implement the cython job
import cosmos_cy

pyxfname.somefunction()
```

When I finish the process of cythonizing, I just need to do `python pyfile.py` to run the file. And things do run properly.

In the above example, when I do not use `somefunction()`, I get an error which says `Buffer types only allowed as function local variables` which is similar to what is described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13024357/converting-python-numpy-code-to-cython-issue-with-arrays-buffer-types-only) post.

Also, I have seen at multiple places ( [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41914252/buffer-types-only-allowed-as-function-local-variables-but-thats-what-im-doing) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51370609/error-while-trying-to-access-elements-of-numpy-array-inside-function-cython) ) that Cython doesn't like having functions inside functions. So, my hands get tied when I want to define more functions in the `pyx` file.

Because of this, **I would like to avoid defining the python function** `somefunction()`. What changes do I need to do in my `pyx` or `py` file (or both) to achieve the desired functionality without having to use python functon? Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Both of the cases you cite are functions defined inside other functions.  I'd hope Cython doesn't have problems with ordinary module-level functions like your `somefunction`.

Comment: I don't understand the question.  If `somefunction()` is really just printing `"Hello world"`, then you do not need Cython to do that in  the first place.  I imagine you actually have some other code you want to put into `somefunction()`, but it is very difficult for us to advise you when we cannot see that code.

Comment: Kevin: My actual is not different (not just `Hello world`). It has a bunch of nested for loops, mathematical calculations. I didn't want the question to be overwhelmingly long. I am editing my post to give a better idea of some things that I am doing.

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to achieve, to me it looks as if you try to share data between different functions. Usually one would encapsulate data + functions working on this data in a class. There are cdef classes in cython, if this is what you want.

Comment: As written this code compiles correctly. Cython won't allow `np.ndarray[...]` types in nested functions or in classes. However __neither of those cases are shown in your code__. Typed memoryviews work fine in these situations though.